# Predicting Missing Word in Text

Tags: nlp, bert

I know about BERT and other solutions when you masking some words and try to predict them.
But let say I have a text:

> Transformer have taken the of Natural Processing
>   by storm, transforming the field by leaps and bounds. New,
>   bigger, and better models to crop up almost every , 
>   benchmarks in performance across a wide variety of tasks.

And I cannot in advance say to BERT where masking is. I am looking for an algorithm which can understand where missing words are and after that predict them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not simple, but doable. I suggest you to create training data in the following way: take a text corpus, as large as possibile, and remove words sampled randomly. Then train an **seq2seq RNN** to map this "deteriorated" text with its original.

The RNN you need won't be too different from an **NMT** model, but it's goal is different of course.

It's the first time I encountered this kind of task, therefore I can't say what is the state of the art.